# Why can't I create a constructor in derived class?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

```
class test1
{
    testName: string;
    testNum: number;
}

class test2 extends test1
{

    constructor(conName:string, conNum: number)
    {

    }
}
```

but it won't work because it says that "Derived class must implement super"

Comment: Add `super()` to the body of the constructor

Comment: You need to call super() in class2 constructor

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using TypeScript super()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37957404/using-typescript-super)

Comment: great. worked but why would it need that ? If i don't use constructor in test2 then it doesn't also need for test1. Why?

Answer (score 13):

The error you are getting is actually:

> Constructors for derived classes must contain a 'super' call

The reason for this is that the base class must be initialized from the derived class by calling the base class constructor (using the `super` keyword).

```
class test1
{
    testName: string;
    testNum: number;
}

class test2 extends test1
{

    constructor(conName:string, conNum: number)
    {
        super()
    }
}
```

Comment: great. worked but why would it need that ? If i don't use constructor in test2 then it doesn't also need for test1. Why?

Comment: @JameelaKhan Typescript will not make assumptions about what the base class constructor does and will force you to call it even if it is empty. (even if the `test1` does not have an explicit constructor it has an implicit one)

Answer (score 2):

You need to call the parent class constructor explicitely

```
class test1
{
    testName: string;
    testNum: number;
}

class test2 extends test1
{

    constructor(conName:string, conNum: number)
    {
        super()
    }
}
```

When you create a class, an empty constructor is automatically created for you. These are equivalent:

```
// implicit
class test1
{
    testName: string;
    testNum: number;
}

// explicit
class test1
{
    testName: string;
    testNum: number;
    public constructor() {

    }
}
```

All child must call their parent constructor explicitely with `super`

> Each derived class that contains a constructorfunction must call `super()` which will execute the constructor of the base class. [•••] This is an important rule that TypeScript will enforce.

From the [doc](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/classes.html)

My guess is that this decision maybe a type check performance tradeoff (source needed). By enforcing this rule, typescript does not have to check if the constructor of the base class is indeed empty.

Comment: great. worked but why would it need that ? If i don't use constructor in test2 then it doesn't also need for test1. Why?

Comment: typescript is not smart enough to know that you defined an empty constructor in your base class

Answer (score 0):

Since you used `extends` on `test2` which is a child of `test1` (more [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/extends)), you will need to call `super()` and pass in anything that belongs in the `test1` constructor. However, since there is nothing to pass, just call `super()` inside of `test2` constructor.

Comment: great. worked but why would it need that ? If i don't use constructor in test2 then it doesn't also need for test1. Why?